# How to convert multiple img files to a vdi?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a `.vdi` file which contains 3 `.img` files as seen in this picture:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6cwF.png)

I have extracted these `.img` files and modified them, now I'm trying to convert them back to a `.vdi` file.

If call the `vboxmanage` command specifying multiple input files, it fails, example:

```
vboxmanage convertfromraw --format VDI 0.img 1.img 2.img test.vdi
```

How i could convert the `.img` files back to a `.vdi`?

Comment: VDI is not an archive format, it looks like 7-Zip extracted the partitions as individual images.  convertfromraw will need the entire disk as one image.  Even if you concatenate the three partition images, you're still missing the first 1048576 bytes of the disk which contain the partition table (and possibly a boot loader).

Comment: @OskarSkog do you know how i could push a file to the vdi?